# Converting json and flatten it to a table in python

Tags: python, json, list, loops, for-loop

I have a category list that already been flattened but not sure how I can convert it to table that looks like below example. So if a has children is equal to false then that will be my id and then if has children is true I'll get the name and so on. I think it can be done by looping the category list

```
"response": {
    "category_list": [
      {
        "category_id": 100017,
        "parent_category_id": 0,
        "name": "Women Clothes",
        "has_children": true
      },
      {
        "category_id": 100118,
        "parent_category_id": 100017,
        "name": "Socks & Stockings",
        "has_children": true
      },
      {
        "category_id": 100419,
        "parent_category_id": 100118,
        "name": "Others",
        "has_children": false
      },
      {
        "category_id": 100418,
        "parent_category_id": 100118,
        "name": "Pantyhose",
        "has_children": false
      },
      {
        "category_id": 100417,
        "parent_category_id": 100118,
        "name": "Socks",
        "has_children": false
      }
]
}
```

So result should be like this:

| Id | Category 1 | Category 2 | Category 3 | Category 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100419 | Women Clothes | Socks & Stockings | Others |  |
| 100417 | Women Clothes | Socks & Stockings | Pantyhose |  |
| 100418 | Women Clothes | Socks & Stockings | Socks |  |

Comment: Why was this reposted?

Comment: And what have you tried?  This is not terribly difficult.  Just keep a dictionary mapping the parent ids to their names.

Comment: @TimRoberts none yet. sorry I'm new to python :(

Comment: @Potatooo people would be far more responsive if you post your attempt first even if it doesn't work. Just asking others to do your work for you is bad form.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great deal you haven't showed us.  Your sample data all has exactly two parents.  Is that universal?  Will there be some with one parent?  Three?

This produces the results you want and should handle arbitrary ancestry.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

rawinp = """\
{
    "response": {
        "category_list": [
          {
            "category_id": 100017,
            "parent_category_id": 0,
            "name": "Women Clothes",
            "has_children": true
          },
          {
            "category_id": 100118,
            "parent_category_id": 100017,
            "name": "Socks & Stockings",
            "has_children": true
          },
          {
            "category_id": 100419,
            "parent_category_id": 100118,
            "name": "Others",
            "has_children": false
          },
          {
            "category_id": 100418,
            "parent_category_id": 100118,
            "name": "Pantyhose",
            "has_children": false
          },
          {
            "category_id": 100417,
            "parent_category_id": 100118,
            "name": "Socks",
            "has_children": false
          }
        ]
    }
}"""

data = json.loads(rawinp)

parents = {}
rows = []
for row in data["response"]["category_list"]:
    if row["has_children"]:
        if row["parent_category_id"]:
            parents[row["category_id"]] = parents[row["parent_category_id"]] + [row["name"]]
        else:
            parents[row["category_id"]] = [row["name"]]
    else:
        rows.append([row["category_id"]] + parents[row["parent_category_id"]] + [row['name']])

pprint(rows)
```

Output:

```
[[100419, 'Women Clothes', 'Socks & Stockings', 'Others'],
 [100418, 'Women Clothes', 'Socks & Stockings', 'Pantyhose'],
 [100417, 'Women Clothes', 'Socks & Stockings', 'Socks']]
```